# adding numbers 100-299 to an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make an array of 200 integers, filled with integers 100-299. I currently have this:

```
int myArray[200];

int j;

for(j = 100; j < 300; j++){

    myArray[j] = j;

}
```

When I display `myArray[0]` and `myArray[200]`, it displays random junk numbers, so I know that my array isn't filling properly. I also have another array filled with `int`s from 0-99, and it's working as intended.

Comment: You never write to `myArray[0]`, so you shouldn't expect it to contain any meaningful value

Comment: You are iterating over the elements at index 100 to 299, but the valid indices for your array are between 0 and 199. You probably meant `myArray[j-100] = j;` instead of `myArray[j] = j;`.

Comment: Since `j` can be as high as 299, what do you think will happen when you assign something to `myArray[299]`, given that the array has only 200 elements?

Comment: *I also have another array filled with ints from 0-99, and it's working as intended.* -- That is because you were plain lucky you started at 0.  You never realized that the code does not work if you started at a different number.  How would your code have worked if you started from -100 and went to 100 `for (int j = -100; j <= 100; ++j)`?  Would `myArray[-100]` make sense to you?

Comment: Sometimes you just have to look hard at the code you've written and ask yourself what's it's actually doing instead of what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 6):

Since `j` loops from 100-299, `myArray[j]` never fills up elements 0-99 of `myArray`, and goes out of bounds for the latter half of the loop.

You want:

```
for (j = 0; j < 200; j++)
{
    myArray[j] = j+100;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int myArray[200];

int j;
//when you say arr[j] with j = 200 for example and you array goes from 0 to 199 of course you will get an error
for(j = 100; j < 300; j++){
   // you are confusing between index of the array you are trying to access  & the the value  to assign it
  //with j-100 now it will go from 100-100=0 to 299-100=199 
    myArray[j-100] = j;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers already demonstrate your mistake, but I want to show an alternative approach using [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

```
int myArray[200];
std::iota(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

your first array index starts from 100 not from 0. 
int myArray[200] means index from 0 to 199.

Answer (score 2):

As others stated, your loop is using the wrong array indexes. Arrays always start at index 0, regardless of the values stored in the array.

You can (and should) use standard algorithms to avoid using a manual loop, thus avoiding such pitfalls.

Such as [`std:::generate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) or [`std::generate_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

```
#include <algorithm>

struct startAt
{ 
    int num;

    startAt(int start) : num(start) {}

    int operator() ()
    {
        return num++;
    }
}

std::generate(myArray, myArray+200, startAt(100));
or
std::generate_n(myArray, 200, startAt(100));
```

Or, if using C++11 or later:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

std::array<int, 200> myArray;

std::generate(myArray,begin(), myArray.end(), [n = 100] () mutable { return n++; });
or
std::generate_n(myArray,begin(), 200, [n = 100] () mutable { return n++; });
```

Or, using [`std::itoa()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead:

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

std::array<int, 200> myArray;

std::iota(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

To fill a raw array with a seqence of numbers, the `std::iota` (from `<numeric>`) with the help of `std::begin` and `std::end` (both from `<iterator>`) come to the resue.

`using ...` is used in the same way we apply `std::swap`, thus if there is a better `begin/end` methods specialications available the correct version for the containers is picked. So if you decide that your container should be a `std::vector` or `std::array` you will not have to modify the code much or at all.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

int myArray[200];
using std::begin;
using std::end;
std::iota(begin(myArray), end(myArray), 100); // this parts is usually within a function body
```

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users